# Highstock dataGrouping adding point to incomplete series

Tags: highcharts

I'm using dataGrouping in a Highstock chart that involves multiple series, the actual years are arbitrary but in this case one of the series is 2011, all the others are 2012.  What I'm noticing is that when dataGrouping is enabled, the 2011 data has a point at dec. 30 2012 and the 2012 data has a point at jan 1 2011, thus drawing lines straight across the chart.  When dataGrouping is disabled this doesnt happen and the chart behaves as you would expect, with one series just ending and the next series beginning.

Has anyone noticed this? Is there a way to avoid it?  So far all I've come up with as a workaround is merging the datasets so all the 2012 series have the 2011 data.

Thanks

Comment: Could you recreate issue on jsFiddle? Are you sure that 2011 series doesn't contain any data for 2012 year? In general it works with `smoothed: false`, see [link](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping). So there shouldn't be point for 30th of December, I think.

Comment: Ah damn. It appears smoothed: false did it.  I thought I tried that already.  anyway, I made the fiddle in case anyone wants to check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/Tu4Q8/    Thanks!